# How to access child of parent in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Trying to get the child of a parent through a child accessor. Basically trying to get the `.block__id` through the `add__block` class.

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-12">
    <span class="block__id">{{$block->id}}</span>
          {{$block->title}}
     <span class="add__block">+</span>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(".add__block").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().find(function(){
          var id = $(".block__id").text();
    });
    console.log(id);
});
```

Currently I get id not defined.

Comment: @pravid it's already in the question...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic is almost correct, but the issue is that you're providing a function to `find()` whereas you simply need to use a selector string:

```js
$(".add__block").click(function() {
  var id = $(this).parent().find(".block__id").text();
  console.log(id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-12">
  <span class="block__id">Block #1</span> 
  Block title
  <span class="add__block">+</span>
</div>
<div class="col-12">
  <span class="block__id">Block #2</span> 
  Block title
  <span class="add__block">+</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very familiar with jQuery, but with vanilla Javascript this is very easy:

```js
const blocks = document.querySelectorAll('.add__block');

for (const block of blocks) {
  block.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.previousElementSibling.textContent)
  })
}
```

```html
<div class="col-12">
    <span class="block__id">{{$block->id}}</span>
          {{$block->title}}
     <span class="add__block">+</span>
</div>
```

Comment: This is perfect.. thanks, but i have to accept the jquery version.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is just looking for the sibling with [`prev`](https://api.jquery.com/prev/) method, which might be slightly faster than going to parent and then search from there.

```js
$('.add__block').click(function(){
    var id = $(this).prev('.block__id').text();
    console.log(id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-12">
  <span class="block__id">Block #1</span> 
  Block title
  <span class="add__block">+</span>
</div>
<div class="col-12">
  <span class="block__id">Block #2</span> 
  Block title
  <span class="add__block">+</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try like below:

```
$(".add__block").click(function(){        
    var id = $(".block__id").text();
    console.log(id);
});
```

Comment: Note that this selects all the `.block__id` elements, not just the one related to the clicked `.add__block` element.

Answer (score 0):

On click you can find the `parent` of the `.add__block` element and find the relevant `.block__id` within the parent as follows,

```
$(".add__block").click(function(){
    console.log($(this).parent().find(".block__id").text(););
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('.add_block').prevAll('span')`